# Generate ultrashort rise times with photoconductive switch or photodiode

Tags: rf, photodiode, pulse, optics, rise-time

I am trying to produce voltage pulses with very short rise time (<15 ps), medium width (20 ns) and amplitudes up to 15 V. As a promising candidate I selected photoconductive switches and ultrafast photodiodes. However, I have limited knowledge about electronics at all and thus, even less knowledge about these devices. Do you think it is possible to produce pulses like that by applying a constant bias DC voltage (for example 15 V) to the switch/diode and send a laser pulse with approx. 20 ns width to the photosensitive area?

I already found photoconductive switches at Hamamatsu and Laser Quantum that might work. In particular, I am talking about the G4176-01 and the Tera-SED3, respectively. However, I cannot imagine how to connect these switches. For the Tera-SED3, one would have to use the ground as the output but how to deal with the grounds than without violating the impedance?

I appreciate any help, advise, new insights and ideas. Also, if you know another supplier of photoconductive switches or photodiodes that might work for my purposes, I would be very grateful if you share these with me.

Comment: This diode is rated at 30ps which is beyond your spec. Do you need a latency lower than 15ps or the edge itself ?

Comment: You also need to consider into what kind of load you want to pulse

Comment: @Damien, yes that is right, but this photoconductive switch would be quite cheap and thus worth a test. With the Tera-SED3 I can go to 1 ps or below. And I am talking about the time from 10% voltage to 90% voltage.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I will use a 50 Ohm coax as transmission line. However, I want to apply the pulses to a capacitor with approx 500 fF to 1 pF. But that is a different problem I think?!

Comment: It seems to be quite hard to achieve, even the best buffer / driver are around the ns level. There are ultra fast op-amp able to drive at that speed but only up to 5V.

Comment: @Damien Can you think of a way to amplify these 5V up to 15V with a large bandwidth device?

Comment: I've looked at common devices but couldn't find anything. I think that's very specific application and will need to find specialized parts done by specialized companies and probably will be very expensive. You are talking 600Ghz even the scope to measure that will cost you several hundred thousand dollars

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Damien, but I think its 60 GHz not 600. But anyway I know this is challenging, but maybe using optical devices like photoconductive switches or photodiodes allow to access this regime. Or other electrical devices like comparators or similar things that I am not aware of?

Comment: Well 60ghz oscilloscope 2 channels is about 400'000$. Maybe someone in this site will have a clever solution but you might need to have a specialized firm to do that. Maybe if you provide more details about the application there might be some other ways around.